# Sqlalchemy using flush() to retrieve primary key (id) smart here?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flush

I have a form where a user can upload images/videos. I create a unique image/video name for the files, to make sure the name is unique I am using the id of the image/video object. To get the id before the `commit()` I am using `flush()`.

```
def profile_add_user_post():
    form = AddUserPostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit(): 
        new_post = Post(title=form.title.data.strip(), description=form.description.data, created_on=datetime.today(), updated_on=datetime.today(), created_by_user_id=current_user.id)

        if form.visible_to_tier_id.data and form.visible_to_tier_id.data != "0":
            setattr(new_post, "visible_to_tier_id", form.visible_to_tier_id.data)

        if form.post_image.data:
            new_image_post = PostImage(path=get_random_code(15), created_on=datetime.today())
            new_post.image_belongs_to_post_addresses.append(new_image_post)
            # multiple add
            db_session.add(new_post)
            db_session.flush()
            image_name = str(new_image_post.id) + "-post-image." + form.post_image.data.filename.split(".")[-1]
            upload_to_aws(image_name, "images/", form.post_image.data)
            setattr(new_image_post, "path", image_name)

        if form.post_video.data:
            new_video_post = PostVideo(path=get_random_code(15), created_on=datetime.today())
            new_post.video_belongs_to_post_addresses.append(new_video_post)
            # multiple add
            db_session.add(new_post)
            db_session.flush()
            video_name = str(new_video_post.id) + "-post-video." + form.post_video.data.filename.split(".")[-1]
            upload_to_aws(video_name, "videos/", form.post_video.data)
            setattr(new_video_post, "path", video_name)

        if form.send_category.data:
            category_list_for_post = form.send_category.data.split(",")
            for cat in category_list_for_post:
                new_cat_post = PostBelongsCategory(category_id=cat)
                new_post.children_PostBelongsCategory.append(new_cat_post)

        # multiple add
        db_session.add(new_post)
        db_session.commit()
        flash("Beitrag erfolgreich hinzugefügt","success")
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    return render_template('profile_add_post.html', form=form)
```

It works great, but couldn't this lead to problems with `IntegretyError`?

A video upload can take a few minutes. But I am asking for the ID before the video has been uploaded, in case another user uploads a video at the same time. The `flush()` could make it possible for both users to have the same video ID, which would lead to one of them to an `IntegretyError` while uploading the video.

So is this an issue in my example? If yes what is the use of `flush()`? I have already found some threads about this but I am not 100% sure yet.

Also if `flush()` is not useful here, how can I make sure (best practice) that the filenames are unique?

I could use my `get_random_code(15)` for the filename, which would generate a random string, the chance that the same string would be generated twice is almost 0. This way I wouldn't need `flush()`. But I do not have more ideas.

Comment: By "video ID" do you mean a serial primary key?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes the ID is the primary key

Comment: [Sequences are not affected by transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095917/sequences-not-affected-by-transactions), or in other words two rows will not receive the same ID, even if you flush in a long transaction. You might get gaps, though, if the transaction rollbacks. But that shouldn't matter.