# Why Postgres id column serial4 type not increment by 1 even not deleting

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

In postgres 11.2 I created a table with `id serial4 NOT NULL`, I thought the `id` would always increment by `1` but I noticed it's not.

Table `Order` creation SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.order (
    "createdAt" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "updatedAt" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "deletedAt" timestamptz NULL,
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    .....
);
```

For example, when I queried `select id from device d where id < 4000000 order by "id" desc limit 10`, some ids are not incremented by `1`

```
id
3999794
3999791
3999668
3999660
3999585
3999578
3999543
3999541
3999334
3999023
```

Although it looks like in some id ranges, the ids are always increment added by 1.

For example:

`select id from device d where id < 2000 order by "id" desc limit 10` or

`select id from device d where id < 5000000 order by "id" desc limit 10`

```
id
1999
1998
1997
1996
1995
1994
1993
1992
1991
1990
```

```
id
4999984
4999983
4999982
4999981
4999980
4999979
4999978
4999977
4999976
4999975
```

are all sequence id rows added by `1`.

Since I always use `soft delete` by the `deletedAt` column and I've checked my code that it would never delete the rows.

Would postgres 11.2 increment data column `serial4` not by `1` but other values in some conditions? How can we prevent it happening?

Comment: The **only** job for a generated value is to be unique. Gaps are expected and not a problem. It's possible to "waste" sequence values when you call `nextval()` but never use the value. Or because of caching of sequence values. There is nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095917/sequences-not-affected-by-transactions

Comment: See [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for a detailed answer.

Comment: Offtopic: Are you sure about version 11.2? That would mean that your server is over 3 years without maintenance. You're missing hundreds of bug fixes, including fixes for data corruption and security issues. Latest version (as of today) is version 11.17

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes, I chose this version for using plv8 ( function in javascript ) about 2 years ago. I haven't updated since then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Laurenz Albe for the link to the awesome article [GAPS IN SEQUENCES IN POSTGRESQL](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/)
.

After testing, in my case, the gaps are caused by column unique constraint, whenever inserting a row of data violate the unique constraint, the `serial4` column would go to the next value.

Some scripts below for reproducing my case:

Run postgres11.2 in docker:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

docker rm -f pg-test
docker run -d --name pg-test postgres:11.2
sleep 5
docker exec -it pg-test bash -c 'psql -U postgres'
```

In psql

```
\e

CREATE TABLE public.order (
    "createdAt" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "updatedAt" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "deletedAt" timestamptz NULL,
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    n1 varchar UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO "order" (n1) VALUES (1); 
// return INSERT 0 1
INSERT INTO "order" (n1) VALUES (1); 
// return ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "order_n1_key" DETAIL:  Key (n1)=(4) already exists.

INSERT INTO "order" (n1) VALUES (2);
// return INSERT 0 1

select * from "order";
```

The select result would be:

```
           createdAt           |           updatedAt           | deletedAt | id | n1
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----+----
 2022-08-26 02:18:03.716084+00 | 2022-08-26 02:18:03.716084+00 |           |  1 | 1
 2022-08-26 02:18:46.831221+00 | 2022-08-26 02:18:46.831221+00 |           |  3 | 2
```

The `id` serial4 column has a gap from `1` to `3` because of `INSERT` that violate the unique contraint.