# How RDBMs like PostgreSQL implement durable sequences and yet not be parts of normal transactions?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, sequence

In PostgreSQL, you can [rollback a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095917/sequences-not-affected-by-transactions) and the sequences continue forward.

But then how are the Sequences *stored in a durable way*? I wanna know how this is implemented (I'm doing an RDBMs) and it looks to me as if exist 2 databases, one for sequences and another for regular tables.

So, it looks like things work this way:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT table (id, name) values (
   next = sequence.next()
   COMMIT(sequence)
   ,
   "hello"
);

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

But how the inner COMMIT not get rolled back?

Comment: Postgres is open source and so is [their implementation](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/sequence.c) of a sequence

Answer (score 0):

As with all other objects, changes to sequences are logged to WAL, so that recovery can restore the state from a backup or after a crash. Since writing WAL impacts performance, not each call to `nextval` will log to WAL. Rather, the first call logs a value 32 numbers ahead of the current value, and the next 32 calls to `nextval` don’t log anything.

You can find this information and more on the topic of sequences and transactions in [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/).

Since you wonder how the `COMMIT` for sequences works in the case of a `ROLLBACK`: there is no special commit for sequences. A WAL record is logged and replayed. In PostgreSQL, transactions are replayed during  recovery, no matter if the transaction is committed or not. Normal table modifications become "invisible" if the transaction is rolled back. But the modifications to the sequence are in place (the sequence row gets overwritten), and nothing becomes invisible after a rollback.

Comment: What is puzzling to me is how the COMMIT for sequences works in the case of a ROLLBACK.